# iOS stream playing

Tags: ios, xcode5, video-streaming

I have a streaming server (like VLC). And I want to play the Video-Streaming(like get broadcast signal) in my iOS devices. 
I tried using `Mediaplayer` Framework. But it can only play the videos which are located on the server.

This is my current code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u 8"];
    movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [movieplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20,100,380,150)];
    [self.view addSubview:movieplayer.view];

    movieplayer.fullscreen=YES;
    movieplayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    movieplayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    movieplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
}
```

Can give me some suggestion to play the Streaming. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the AVFoundation framework. I'd recommend reading up on the documentation. But essentially, you can create an AVPlayerItem with the URL of the HTTP live stream. You can then create an AVPlayer with the AVPlayerItem and the appropriate AVPlayerLayer. Then you're pretty much good to go. Here is some sample code to get you going in the right direction:

```
AVPlayerItem *videoPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.videoURL];

AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:videoPlayerItem];
```